# How to add Ojdbc14.jar in maven local repository?

Tags: java, oracle, maven

Whenever I am trying to add

```
<groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
<version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
```

in maven dependencies it shows Missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.2.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Download it from somewhere and follow these instructions: [Maven - Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Comment: Do you use entreprise Maven repository such as Nexus or Artifactory ?

Comment: Is jar available in your repo ? Can you show how you are adding dependency ? Have you tried to clean and then build again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install oracle jar file to your local repository manually [See here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

From command line you can run:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-jar-file> -DgroupId=com.oracle \
-DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.0.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

You can download the jar file [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html)